# simplification of a complex expression

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I am collecting proofs for certain integrals. To simplify certain proofs, I use 
$e^{Ax}cos(Bx)=\mathcal{Re}[e^{(A+iB)x}]$, where $A$, $B$, and $x$ are real. Is there an analogous simplification for $ e^{iAx} cos(Bx) $? Thanks.

Comment: Well $e^{Ax}\sin(Bx)=\mathfrak{Im}[e^{(A+iB)x}]$, but that's not what you asked.